# Need to refine this regex expression

Tags: regex, pcre

The input I can get might be

```
/DemoSystems/DemoFramework/MyRepo/MyModule/tags/2015_02_22
```

or

```
/DemoSystems/DemoFramework/MyRepo/MyModule/tags/2015_02_22/Demo.Tests/AverageTests.cs
```

I need to extract in both cases.

```
/DemoSystems/DemoFramework/MyRepo/MyModule/tags/2015_02_22
```

Regex:

```
^(.*?)tags
```

is matching till

```
/DemoSystems/DemoFramework/MyRepo/MyModule/tags
```

And added complexity is that 2015_02_22 can be anything. A mix of number alphabets and whitespaces. Basically depends on developer. So in other words I have to match till 'tags' + the next folder after it.

Any pointers?

Comment: No pointers, but I might have some metacharacters :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
.*?tags\/[^\/]+
```

It will match anything from the start of the line until the word `tags`, the `/` after the word `tags` and the following characters until another `/` (excluding that) or the end of the string.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW5yO6/2)

Comment: You are welcome. Also note, that you don't need the `()` unless you want to capture the content before the word `tags` separately.

Comment: @DeDee There is a cooling period of 10 mins I guess so that others can add inputs before the answer can be accepted. :)